# error:FetchError: request to https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/files failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.120.251.101:443

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

When i write node utils/nftport/uploadFiles.js in the terminal, I just get "error:FetchError: request to https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/files failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.120.251.101:443"

When the goal is to get new urls in the json files. Please explain as simple as you can, im really technically dumb.

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const path = require("path")
const basePath = process.cwd();
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readdirSync(`${basePath}/build/images`).forEach((file) => { 
    const formData = new FormData();
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(`${basePath}/build/images/${file}`);
    formData.append('file',fileStream);

    let url = 'https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/files';

    let options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: '[...]',
      },
      body: formData
    };
    
    fetch(url, options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
       const fileName = path.parse(json.file_name).name;
       let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(`${basePath}/build/json/${fileName}.json`);
       let metaData = JSON.parse(rawdata);

       metaData.file_url = json.ipfs_url;

       fs.writeFileSync(`${basePath}/build/json${fileName}.json`, JSON.stringify(metaData, null, 2));

       console.log(`${json.file_name} uploaded & ${fileName}.json updated!`);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));
})
```